# Generators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I am trying to create a Generator in typescript but I'm getting an error *Generators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher* while compiling with `tsc .\Generator.ts .\test.ts`. When I specify the *"--target es6"* when compiling, I have realized that my classes are not compiled correctly, such as my **test.js** includes `import Generator from './Generator';` which is the **same as one in test.ts**

Generator.ts

```
export class Generator {
    val = 0;

    *next() {
      this.val++;
      yield this.val;
    }
}
```

test.ts

```
import {Generator} from './Generator';

let gen = new Generator();

let n = gen.next();
console.log(n);
```

Comment: You must set the `--downLevelIteration` flag to transpile such code to < ES2015. Regarding transpilation of `import`/`export`, you need to decide on your target module format by specifying `--module` don't rely on the implicit behavior of this option.

Comment: @Aluan When I specify `--module  commonjs`, nothing changes. Most probably default value is that. For --downLevelIteration, my tsc gives an error `Unknown compiler option 'downleveliteration'`, I don't know why but its explanation is '(boolean) Provide full support for iterables in for..of, spread and destructuring when targeting ES5 or ES3.', seems not related

Comment: Please indicate your TypeScript version

Comment: @Aluan I'm using  tsc 1.5.3.
I've seen a note _These options are only allowed in tsconfig.json, and not through command-line switches._  [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) As for the --downLevelIteration, and I'm trying on command line, although I'm including a tsconfig.json, it is skipped.

Comment: You are 3 major versions out of date. If you want support, upgrade to TypeScript 4.1

Comment: @Aluan sorry for misinformation, I have rechecked and it's 4.1.3. Without using npx, it returns another thing I guess.

Comment: Your global version is out of date run `npm i -g typescript`

Comment: Thanks @Aluan, that's right. When compile with latest version it has worked 

Comment: Off-topic for this question, but when it made to work, your `next` method will not work as you might expect... (The `next` method will return a real generator object having its own `next` method returning an object with `value` and `done` properties)...